# How can I collapse items in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´ve got a problem with collapsing boxes. For better understanding please check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rnvoh7ms/27/

```js
    function expand(){
    var e1 = document.getElementById("e1");
      e1.style.width = "100%";
      e1.style.height = "600px";
      e1.style.marginLeft = "30px";
      e1.style.marginRight = "30px";
    }
    
    function fold(){
    var e1 = document.getElementById("e1");
      e1.style.width = "400px";
      e1.style.height = "400px";
      e1.style.marginLeft = "0px";
      e1.style.marginRight = "0px";
    }
```

```css
    #wrapper {
      margin: auto;
      width: 90%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-around;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .tile {
      float: left;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 60px 0 0 0;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      border-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
      transition-delay: 0s;
      transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
    
    <!-- This box(1)... -->
    <div class="tile" id="e1">
    <p>folded<br><br></p>
    <p>this content is different to the LOWER box´s content</p>
          <img id="arrow-down" value="change width" onclick="expand()" src="https://imageog.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/25/25623.png?size=1200x630f&pad=10,10,10,10&ext=png&bg=FFFFFFFF" style="width:         40px; display: block; margin: auto; bottom: 0px;" />
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- ...should get transformed into this box -->
    <div class="tile" id="e1" style="background-color: lightblue; width: 90%; height: 600px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <p>unfolded</p>
    <p>this content is different to the UPPER box´s content</p>
          <img id="arrow-up "value="change width" onclick="fold()" src="https://imageog.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/25/25649.png?size=1200x630f&pad=10,10,10,10&ext=png&bg=FFFFFFFF" style="width: 40px; display: block; margin: auto; bottom: 0px;" />
    </div>
    
    <!-- Box (2)... -->
    <div class="tile" id="e1">
    <p>folded<br><br></p>
    <p>I am just another box and I want to behave like the first one</p>
          <img id="arrow-down" value="change width" onclick="expand()" src="https://imageog.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/25/25623.png?size=1200x630f&pad=10,10,10,10&ext=png&bg=FFFFFFFF" style="width:         40px; display: block; margin: auto; bottom: 0px;" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

I want the upper box(1) is getting bigger in it´s width and height by clicking the "down-arrow" you can see there. Then, by clicking the "up-arrow" the transformed version (lower box) should transform back in it´s old form (upper box). In addition, I want to show completely different content in the two box-states.

I am confused about it, especially the JS is only working for one box when I put multiple of this boxes in the HTML.

I´ve linked jQuery with this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're linking in jQuery but using document.getElementByID.  You could use $('#e1').   Also, all of your boxes have the same id. Best practice, you would use a different ID for each.

Comment: You have two ids that are the same. That's something you'll want to avoid altogether, and it is also what is likely breaking your expand and fold functions.

Answer (score 0):

You fiddle doesn't demonstrate anything. Your issue might be in `id` that is the same for all boxes. The `id` of a container should be unique. You have the same `id` for different boxes.